# How are passthroughViews working in UIPopoverPresentationController?

Tags: ios

I'm using [`UIPopoverPresentationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html) and after showing a popover multiple times I get the error

```
UIPopoverPresentationController (<UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x7b259aa0>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.
```

The interesting part is that this is another instance than I used. I have a `sourceView` which isn't nil. My instance is 0x7b615680 and not 0x7b259aa0.

Now the question is where is this instance coming from and why is it used instead of mine? As far as I know iOS manages the lifetime by itself, so no strong reference is required (like in iOS 7) and there should be no memory management issues.

Does iOS needs everytime the fresh `popoverPresentationController` property from the view controller, despite it is the same view controller but with different data? I tried that but I also get the error after some time.

**Edit:**

Now I found out, that if I don't set `passthroughViews` then it works without crashing. So what is wrong with `passthroughViews`? In which view hierarchy has a view in `passthroughViews` to be?

It does work with `nil`, `new UIView()` and `new UICollectionViewCell()`, but neither with an instance of `UICollectionView` nor with an instance of `UICollectionViewCell` ...

Also setting the `passthroughViews` in the [completion handler](http://karmeye.com/2014/11/20/ios8-popovers-and-passthroughviews/) didn't help.

Furthermore I can show and dismiss the popover everytime without a crash if I start the popover from the same `UIView` with the same view controller and content. The app only crashes if I directly select one of the passthrough views! Is using `DismissViewController` the wrong way?

Now I tried to use the default `UIViewController` for the content of the popover and the behavior is the same. So it's not the content of the popover.

**Edit 2:**

Perhaps the problem occur because the view in the `UICollectionView` can't be used as `passthroughViews`. Has anyone of you tried that? I didn't find any solution, so the only solution for me is to not use `passthroughViews` on iOS 8 and up. On iOS 7 it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverPresentationController *popup;

we have to define in header file to prevent such kind of warnings and error with strong reference.

Comment: Should I overwrite the property every time I want to display the popover, because I can only access the `UIPopoverPresentationController` by getting it directly from the presented view controller ...